# Spark Left directjoin(on/off) produces different results

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

we have a different resultset sizes depending on directJoin use on our spark cassandra cluster:

//newpos is a dataframe loaded from cassandra

```
val with_direct_join = new_pos.join(
    right
        .directJoin(AlwaysOn)
    ,
    Seq("a", "b", "c"),
    "left"
```

println("(Direct-Join):  %d".format(with_direct_join.count));    //12006 rows

same dataframe and join with directJoin(AlwayOff) has a result set of //14705 rows

Any ideas why this happens? Directjoin in combination with left join seems to limit rows somehow.

Thanks,
Flo

Comment: how many nodes in the C* cluster, do you run repairs regularly?

Comment: thanks, Alex, you are fast :) 3 Nodes actually, repairs - as far as I know - are on default setting that means no repairs, right? , need to ask the C* Admin today, but this is getting me in a direction I was not expecting. Would an outdated replica behave different in directjoin situation?

Comment: By default there is no repairs... The direct join just performs requests to individual partitions/primary keys, and may hit not repaired replicas as well, and because by default the LOCAL_ONE is used, then you may get outdated data.  You may try to to start your application with `--conf spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=ALL` and try again - if you have any inconsistency it will be repaired during the read, although job may fail because of the delays with repairing data

Comment: thanks Alex, I will check with the admin and devs and let you know